# Comparing 2 workbooks for missing sheet in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I had a requirement which is in excel macro. Here is the scenario :

I have 2 workbooks, Say A and B

Workbook "A" contains, sheet 1, sheet2 and sheet3, Workbook "B" contains sheet4

Now i need to compare Workbook "B" with Workbook A. If a sheet exist in Workbook "A" which is not in Workbook "B" (Here Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) then i need to add these 3 sheets to Workbook "B"

So finally, B workbook should contain : Sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3 and sheet 4.

Tried below code but its not working.

```
Set act = ThisWorkbook
path = Sheet1.TextBox1.Text
Set owb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    a = ws.Name
    For Each ws1 In owb.Worksheets
       If ws1.Name = a Then
          MsgBox "Found"
       Else
          Set wsnew = owb.Sheets.Add
          wsnew.Name = a
       End If
     Next ws1
Next ws
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on how the code is not working

Comment: sure, it throwing error as "Name already exists". In fact it creates sheet but loop not ending.

Comment: At which line does the error is raised? And what sheet name are you trying to set when the error is raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than check each worksheet you could try and set a reference to it - if the reference is set then the sheet exists, if it throws an error then it doesn't exist.

I'd use a separate function to return TRUE/FALSE on the sheet existing - one of the few times that I'd use `On Error Resume Next` to ignore any errors.

```
Public Sub CopySheets()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim wrkShtNew As Worksheet

    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Book2")

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not WorkSheetExists(wrkSht.Name, wrkBk) Then
            Set wrkShtNew = wrkBk.Worksheets.Add
            wrkShtNew.Name = wrkSht.Name
        Else
            MsgBox wrkSht.Name & " exists.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If wrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```